# Changing Binded ObservableCollection Instance

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a slight issue which I'm not sure is really a problem but the cynic in me thinks I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

I have a view model with a Property which is an ObservableCollection of sub models to be displayed:

```
    public SeatingPlanItemCollection DisplayItems
    {
        get 
        {
            return _displayItems; 
        }
        private set
        {
            SetField(ref _displayItems, value, () => DisplayItems);
        }
    }
```

This is then bound through XAML to an ItemControl's ItemSource property.  From certain commands this collection can be changed within the model, when running the code everything is fine, the collection changes and the ItemsControls refreshes perfectly well and promptly. However I noticed that sometimes whilst debugging that the change would be exceptionally slow and a whole bunch of binding errors would be displayed in the output window.  This only happens if I have broken into the code at any point before the property change.  If I am in debug mode but have not broken in at any point then everything is fine and no binding errors are reported.

Thinking about it, this does make sense, controls are bound to the items in the collection, the collection is then changed and breaking the bindings, the collection then raises it's collection changed event and the View rebinds sucessfully.

What I would like to know is :

1. Why do the binding errors only output after I have broken into the code?
2. Is this something to worry about as the slowness only appears to be apparent after breaking into the code which obviously would not happen in production? (Although I assume there could still be a minor performance hit behind the scenes which I am not aware of, the major one I notice is the runtime environment emitting the errors to the output window).
3. If it is a problem, how should I handle changing the collection that the ItemsControl is bound to?

Hope that is clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

**EDIT**

At one point I figured that changes the instance of the collection was probably the issue so I decided to instead a dedicated collection instance and when it needed to be changed I cleared it and then added all the new items, the same issue occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that Outputting binding errors to the output window slows down WPF significantly for some reason I have noticed this myself.  I turn it off If I dont need it.

Comment: I think you may very well be right, my original thought was not to be too concerned by it but that mentality sometimes gets me into trouble so I thought I would investigate. I turned down the data binding tracing from verbose to error (I forgot that I had turned it up to verbose yesterday) and it's now not occurring.  Thanks for your input.